# New warnings in iOS9: Ambiguous expansion of macro 'TARGET_OS_IOS'

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-warnings, ios9

After upgrading Xcode to version 7 and using iOS SDK 9 these warnings appear in:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IOS
```

Warning:

```
Ambiguous expansion of macro 'TARGET_OS_IOS'
```

How do I make it go away?

Comment: Does the compiler give any more detail?

Comment: What happens if you right click on the symbol and *Find Definition*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have defined `TARGET_OS_IOS` in your own code you need to change it to something else (or delete your version)

Xcode 7 newly defines it for itself along with `TARGET_OS_WATCH`

Comment: It's not mine, it's `TargetConditionals.h` defined by Xcode

Comment: OK - Does the warning inspector on the left (CMD-4 )provide you with any more detail. It might say where it has been defined in other places.

Comment: No, I have 10 errors at the same file with the same error and no details about the errors..

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [the Warren Burton answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32690794/4915707): `TARGET_OS_IOS` may be defined not only in your code but also in project settings in XCode in `Preprocessor Macros`